# How can I do secure SAML with multiple tenants?

Tags: node.js, security, passport.js, saml

I'm talking in the context of a IDP-initiated workflow.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml) `passport` strategy for saml. Under the "[Security and signatures](https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml#security-and-signatures)" heading, it suggests providing the IDP's cert.

This cert would be inserted when I define the strategy AFAIK.

In the case of a multi-tenant application, I would have no way of knowing which cert to use until the user attempted to log in, and at that point it would be to late to use the cert, wouldn't it?

How can I authenticate SAML requests with multiple tenants if I can't know which cert to use until the SAML requests come in?

I'm thinking I'd need something like this:

1. User sends information identifying which tenant they're trying to login to
2. The SAML strategy is created with the correct cert.
3. The SAML process starts.

Or perhaps I'm just thinking about it wrong, and none of this is really necessary for having a relatively secure login process?

If this question is too broad, I'd appreciate it if you left comments to help me narrow it down, or directed me to resources that I should read.

---

If it wasn't clear, I'm storing:

- The SSO Url
- The Issuer url
- The public cert

This information is linked to the tenant, so once I get the profile information from the IDP, I can identify which tenant the user should be directed to. I can also use this information after the tenant is identified to validate things.

Perhaps I can just use the public cert to do some "after-the-fact" validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it'll work to do this:

1) Provide the tenant Admin with their unique tenant id

2) Have them set the SSO URL to something like "mySite.com/login/[tenantId]",

3) grab the tenantId from the url and use that to choose the correct cert to authenticate against.

This works along with adding middleware to my server to call a function that creates the passport strategy.

Comment: Hello @Houseman, we'd love to know more about how you did this! How do you add a dynamic parameter ("[tenantId]" in your case) to the SSO URL which appears to be a static parameter of (in our case) the SAML strategy config...

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune  The `tenantId` was static to the particular tenant. They'd send their unique id  to us, and we'd use that to determine which cert to use on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help as I am not familiar with passport. That said, when I have designed multi-tenant SAML Service Provider (SP) to Identity Provider (IdP) data flows, I implemented an IdP Discovery service prior to the SAML request being issued. In order to make IdP Discovery work there are a few strategies, but the one that always seems to work best is having the tenant names in the URL as subdomain, e.g. tenant.yourcompany.com.  Then when that URL is processed in the IdP Discovery service it can properly format the SAML Request to the IdP Server.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me the term "IdP Discovery". I'm not sure if doing `tenant.mycompany.com` will work with out setup, though, but now I have another google tool to use!

Comment: The other term of art is WAYF, "Where are you from."  Take a look at https://www.switch.ch/aai/support/tools/wayf/.